# Unable to use mongoimport function in mongo

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to import data(.json) through mongo shell, but I got this...

> mongoimport -d ceshi -c datasample user/civycheng/desktop/sample.json
>   2017-01-18T21:28:17.739+0800 E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

I have no idea how to fix it...can anyone do me a favour?

Comment: what data do you want to import?

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously using a wrong command. From [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/):

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection yourCollectionName < path_to_collection.json
```

For instance, if you have `myCollection.json` in `/home/collections`, a db called `testDb` and you want to call your new collection `testCollection` you should do:

```
mongoimport --db testDb --collection testCollection < /home/collections/myCollection.json
```

Before anything else, make sure you have your `mongo service` on.